# Warning when saving a GdkPixbuf to file - why does it occur?

Tags: gtk, gdkpixbuf

When I save GdkPixbuf contents into a file (which is supposed to be created, path determined via dialog window) using `gdk_pixbuf_save(picturePixbuf, currentFileName, "bmp", &error, NULL);` I get a warning:

```
(app.exe:2012): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to retrieve the file info for `file:///C:/file.png': Error stating file 'C:\file.png': No such file or directory
```

Why? The file is actually being created.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. You should report it on bugzilla.gnome.org.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. I always get this message when my program opens a "where to save this file"-dialog, and I read somewhere that is apparently normal because GTK checks if the file exists to for example not automatically overwrite it when it already exists

Answer (score 0):

You are running into this bug: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=662814 - please update your version of GTK+; this bug has been fixed already and newer versions (of either GTK+ 2.24 or GTK+ 3.x) don't print that warning.